# How to customize seekbar android

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar

Hello i am trying to customize a seekbar on android but i think there is something wrong on thumb view. the problem is two side of thumb.
hear is my code.

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="10"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thm_s"
    android:secondaryProgress="5"
    android:progress="5"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_background"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="94dp" />
```

thm_s.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
<solid
    android:color="#ffffff"/>
<size
    android:width="20dp"
    android:height="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

seekbar_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="#403F41"
            android:startColor="#403F41" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#00AEEF"
                android:startColor="#00AEEF" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

please view this image.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxpdBDS2CMCWTExFREVqVmt6Nk0/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Why are you using `@android:id/secondaryProgress` instead of `@android:id/background`?